# ImportError: cannot import name '__version__' from 'download_espa_order'

Tags: python, github

I have the following error : ImportError: cannot import name '**version**' from 'download_espa_order'
When running this command in my shell :

```
pip install git+https://code.usgs.gov/espa/bulk-downloader.git
```

Can someone help me with this ?
This is where I found this code : https://code.usgs.gov/espa/bulk-downloader/-/blob/develop/README.md

My python version is 3.11.3 and the requests package is already installed
I tried to upgrade pip and python but I did not do change anything

Answer (score 0):

Check python version campatibility, The code may not be compatible with Python 3.11.3 if it was developed for an earlier version.

Comment: I tried to run this command with the 3.6.4 version of python thanks to pyenv and got the exact same error

Comment: Hi Venomous, please look up this information yourself instead of asking the topic starter this information. Or, ask this question bellow the question.